# Stop actix server if scheduled task dies

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm playing with an actix server where I have a scheduled task.

I want the entire server to stop in case the thread running the task dies. As I was expecting, adding a `panic` in the task code will only kill the thread.

This is what I have right now:

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    env_logger::init();

    actix_rt::spawn(async move {
        let mut interval = actix_rt::time::interval(Duration::from_secs(10));
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            schedule_task().await.unwrap();
            // panic!("Killing thread");
        }
    });

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .wrap(Logger::default())
            .service(ping)
            .route("*", web::post().to(echo))
    })
        .bind(("0.0.0.0", 9124))?
        .run()
        .await
```

I know spawn returns a task handler, but I can't await on that to check if it's an error, since I can't start my server.

Not sure if this can be solved around the current implementation. Should I start my scheduled task differently / is there any way to bind the server to the thread lifetime?

Thanks!

Comment: `catch_unwind()`+`std::process::abort()`?

Comment: Not sure about the usage, I'm new to rust. Tried wrapping the code within async move in a `catch_unwind()`, but the compiler complains I can't use await since it's not in an async block any longer.

Comment: After looking a bit into it, I think you weren't talking about the panic::catch_unwind(), but rather using catch_unwind() on the future.

Tried that as well, but now I'm getting `may contain interior mutability and a reference may not be safely transferrable across a catch_unwind boundary`.

I simplified the code a bit, I'm passing a prometheus counter to the method, which I think is the source now for the error.

Comment: You can use [`catch_unwind()` of `futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.catch_unwind). If the compiler is complaining you can wrap in `AssertUnwindSafe`. this is fine since you abort anyway.

Comment: Managed to make it work, thanks! If you submit an answer I'd be happy to accept.